# ListViewItem without CheckBox on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, listview, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml, listviewitem

I would like to have ListView in my Windows Phone 8.1 app but without selection checkbox on every item. So i made ItemTemplate like below but there are still checkboxes on the left side of my list. I can't use ListBox because I need menu flyout on every item and it doesn'r work on ListBoxItems. Can anyone tell me how to remove them?

Here is my xaml

```
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Background="SteelBlue" Holding="UIElement_OnHolding">
                        <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                            <MenuFlyout>

                                <MenuFlyoutItem Text="favorite"
                                                Command="{Binding DataContext.InitExchangeCommand, 
                                                ElementName=ContentRoot}"/>
                            </MenuFlyout>
                        </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>

                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="70"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="../Assets/simple_book.png" Height="55"/>

                        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
                            <TextBlock FontSize="15">
                                                <Run Text="{Binding id}"/>
                                                <Run Text=" - "/>
                                                <Run Text="Historia węża - Jan Anonim"/>
                            </TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock FontSize="15">
                                                <Run Text="Stan: "/>
                                                <Run Text="{Binding state}"/>
                            </TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock FontSize="15">
                                                <Run Text="Typ wymiany:"/> 
                                                <Run Text="{Binding exchange_type}"/>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>

            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need edit ItemContainerStyle and remove CheckboxTiltContainer

```
<Style x:Key="ListViewItemStyle1" TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Local"/>
        <Setter Property="IsHoldingEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemMargin}"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Border x:Name="OuterContainer" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                        <Border.RenderTransform>
                            <ScaleTransform x:Name="ContentScaleTransform"/>
                        </Border.RenderTransform>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition From="Pressed" To="Normal">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TiltContainer"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualTransition>
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TiltContainer"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="CheckboxPressed"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDisabledThemeOpacity}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter"/>

                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedBorder">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedEarmark">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedGlyph">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                    <Storyboard>

                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedCheckMark"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="SelectedUnfocused">
                                    <Storyboard>

                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedCheckMark"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DataVirtualizationStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="DataAvailable"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="DataPlaceholder">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextBlock">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderRect">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="MultiSelectStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition From="ListMultiSelect" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.15" To="NoMultiSelect"/>
                                    <VisualTransition From="NoMultiSelect" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.15" To="ListMultiSelect"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualState x:Name="NoMultiSelect"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="ListMultiSelect">
                                    <Storyboard>

                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="{ThemeResource ListViewItemContentTranslateX}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentBorderTranslateTransform"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="GridMultiSelect">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedBorder"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ReorderModeStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition From="ReorderEnabled" GeneratedDuration="00:00:00.2" To="ReorderDisabled"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualState x:Name="ReorderEnabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DropTargetItemThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="OuterContainer"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Reorderable">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentScaleTransform">
                                            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.075" Value="1.05"/>
                                            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.2" Value="1.0"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentScaleTransform">
                                            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.075" Value="1.05"/>
                                            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.2" Value="1.0"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="ReorderDisabled"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ReorderHintStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.2" To="NoReorderHint"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualState x:Name="NoReorderHint"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="BottomReorderHint">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DragOverThemeAnimation Direction="Bottom" ToOffset="{ThemeResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}" Storyboard.TargetName="ReorderHintContent"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="RightReorderHint">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DragOverThemeAnimation Direction="Right" ToOffset="{ThemeResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}" Storyboard.TargetName="ReorderHintContent"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="TopReorderHint">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DragOverThemeAnimation Direction="Top" ToOffset="0" Storyboard.TargetName="ReorderHintContent"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="LeftReorderHint">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DragOverThemeAnimation Direction="Left" ToOffset="0" Storyboard.TargetName="ReorderHintContent"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Grid x:Name="ReorderHintContent" Background="Transparent">
                            <Border x:Name="ContentContainer">
                                <Border x:Name="TiltContainer">
                                    <Border x:Name="ContentBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                        <Border.RenderTransform>
                                            <TranslateTransform x:Name="ContentBorderTranslateTransform"/>
                                        </Border.RenderTransform>
                                        <Grid>
                                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                                            <TextBlock x:Name="PlaceholderTextBlock" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" Foreground="{x:Null}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Opacity="0" Text="Xg"/>
                                            <Rectangle x:Name="PlaceholderRect" Fill="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Border>
                                </Border>
                            </Border>
                            <Border x:Name="SelectedBorder" BorderBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush}" BorderThickness="{ThemeResource GridViewItemMultiselectBorderThickness}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0">
                                <Grid x:Name="SelectedCheckMark" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="34" Opacity="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="34">
                                    <Path x:Name="SelectedEarmark" Data="M0,0 L40,0 L40,40 z" Fill="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush}" Stretch="Fill"/>
                                    <Path x:Name="SelectedGlyph" Data="M0,123 L39,93 L124,164 L256,18 L295,49 L124,240 z" Fill="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckThemeBrush}" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="14.5" Margin="0,1,1,0" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="17"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```